# JSON ASP.NET static methods

Tags: asp.net, json

How come the method called from Client-side has to be a static method? The issue i am facing is that if the method is static then I can't access my server side controls such as CheckBoxPanel.

Is there any workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

The method is static so that the server doesn't need to create an instance of the `Page` class just to run the method.

Even if the method wasn't static, you wouldn't be able to use the controls in the page anyway, because the form data in the page isn't posted to the server when you make a `PageMethod` call. You need to send all the information that the method needs in the call itself.

Comment: Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: @user3514987: Not as lightweight as `PageMethod` calls. You can use Ajax controls to get a similar function, but with the complete postback so that the page object is available.

Comment: Should I use web services and return Json from there?

Comment: @user3514987: You can do that, but it won't give you access to any server side controls in the page.

Comment: The thing is that I Want to use more client side programming and only use ser side for login and database access etc etc.. Then in my pages I can use do the logic and parse it to the web service.

Comment: Or is there any better approaches

Comment: @user3514987: It sounds like it should work, but I don't know enough of what you want to do to know if it fits. As it's a completely different question I think that you should make it an actual question, where you can describe more about what you do, and get input from others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510387/asp-net-and-sql-server-client-side-calls?noredirect=1#comment43451012_27510387